# None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

Tags: c#, autofac

I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to
>   create a controller of type
>   'App.Web.Controllers.ContractWizardController'. Make sure that the
>   controller has a parameterless public constructor. --->
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors
>   found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'App.Web.Controllers.ContractWizardController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'App.Service.IWizardTypeStepService wizardTypeStepService' of
>   constructor 'Void .ctor(App.Service.IWizardTypeStepService,
>   App.Service.IAppBrandService, App.Service.IAppInstitutionService)'.
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) 
>   at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
>   context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
>   context, Type serviceType)    at
>   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            // Autofac and Automapper configurations
            Bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
namespace App.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            SetAutofacContainer();
            //Configure AutoMapper
            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        }

        private static void SetAutofacContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

            // Repositories
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AppBrandRepository).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            // Services
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AppBrandService).Assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerRequest();


            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
}
```

**IRepository**

```
namespace App.Data.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        // Marks an entity as new
        void Add(T entity);
        // Marks an entity as modified
        void Update(T entity);
        // Marks an entity to be removed
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        // Get an entity by int id
        T GetById(int id);
        // Get an entity using delegate
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        // Gets all entities of type T
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        // Gets entities using delegate
        IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    }
}
```

**RepositoryBase**

```
namespace App.Data.Infrastructure
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        #region Properties
        private ApplicationDbContext dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

        protected IDbFactory DbFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        protected ApplicationDbContext DbContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
        }
        #endregion

        protected RepositoryBase(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
            dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        #region Implementation
        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> objects = dbSet.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
            foreach (T obj in objects)
                dbSet.Remove(obj);
        }

        public virtual T GetById(int id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet.ToList();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        }

        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

**WizardTypeStepRepository**

```
namespace App.Data.Repositories
{
    public class WizardTypeStepRepository : RepositoryBase<WizardTypeStep>, IWizardTypeStepRepository
    {
        public WizardTypeStepRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory) : base(dbFactory)
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<StepNav> StepNav(string langCode = "en", int wizardType = 1)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()) 
            {
                var step = from a in db.Steps
                           join b in db.ItemLanguages
                           on a.ItemCode equals b.ItemCode
                           where b.LangCode == langCode
                           where a.WizardTypeId == wizardType
                           select new StepNav
                           {
                               StepNo = a.StepNo,
                               ItemLegend = b.ItemLegend,
                               Url = a.Url
                           };
                return step;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IWizardTypeStepRepository : IRepository<WizardTypeStep>
    {
        IEnumerable<StepNav> StepNav(string langCode = "en", int wizardType = 1);
    }
}
```

**WizardTypeStepService**

```
namespace App.Service
{
    public interface IWizardTypeStepService
    {
        IEnumerable<WizardTypeStep> GetSteps(int Id);
        IEnumerable<StepNav> AllSteps(string language = "en", int type = 1);
    }
    public class WizardTypeStepService
    {
        private readonly IWizardTypeStepRepository wizardTypeStepRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public WizardTypeStepService(IWizardTypeStepRepository wizardTypeStepRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.wizardTypeStepRepository = wizardTypeStepRepository;
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IEnumerable<WizardTypeStep> GetSteps(int Id)
        {
            return wizardTypeStepRepository.GetMany(a => a.WizardTypeId == Id).OrderBy(a => a.StepNo);
        }


        public IEnumerable<StepNav> StepNav(string language = "en", int type = 1)
        {
            return wizardTypeStepRepository.StepNav(language, type);
        }
    }
}
```

**ContractWizardController**

```
namespace App.Web.Controllers {
    public class ContractWizardController : AppController
    {
        private readonly IWizardTypeStepService wizardTypeStepService;
        public ContractWizardController(IWizardTypeStepService wizardTypeStepService, IAppBrandService brand, IAppInstitutionService institution) : base(brand, institution)
        {
            this.wizardTypeStepService = wizardTypeStepService;

            IEnumerable<StepNav> steps = wizardTypeStepService.AllSteps();
            this.Steps = new StepNavViewModel(steps)
            {
                Steps = steps
            };
            this.ViewData["Steps"] = this.Steps;
        }
    // GET: ContractWizard
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Step(int Id = 1)
    {
        ViewBag.Step = Id;
        switch (Id)
        {
            case 1:
                ViewBag.Title = "State";
                ViewBag.Message = "State content goes here...";
                break;
            case 2:
                ViewBag.Title = "Property";
                ViewBag.Message = "Property Content goes here...";
                break;
            case 3:
                ViewBag.Title = "Listing Agent";
                ViewBag.Message = "Listing Agent content goes here...";
                break;
            case 4:
                ViewBag.Title = "Selling Agent";
                ViewBag.Message = "Selling Ageng content goes here...";
                break;
            case 5:
                ViewBag.Title = "Finish";
                ViewBag.Message = "Finish content goes here...";
                break;
        }
        return View();
    }

    public StepNavViewModel Steps { get; set; }
} }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message tells you that :

> Cannot resolve parameter 'App.Service.IWizardTypeStepService wizardTypeStepService'

Your registration of the corresponding service is like this :

```
// Services
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AppBrandService).Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .InstancePerRequest();
```

But if you look at `WizardTypeStepService`, it doesn't implement any interfaces. Implement `IWizardTypeStepService` and your error should disappear.